Why does my HDD speed drop sometimes?
I have a PC, with a HDD inside. Sometimes the self copy speed (from itself to itself) dropped for no apparent reason from ~50 MB/s to 0,5 MB/sec. According to SMART, the health dropped to 54%, so I replaced it.
Now the new HDD does the same thing, access is sometimes inexplicably slow. I think now it is not because of the drive itself.
I guess it could be the power supply, the motherboard, or the cable. How can I figure out which? (without replacing any of them to test)
Windows 11, copying 1 big file (3 GB), not many small ones.

"I think now it is not because of the drive itself." - Rather than just "think" (aka guess), at least perform the long/extended SMART test on the drive(s). So far you seem to have merely performed a substitution. The proper way to test by substitution is to replace with a known, working component, not just a "new" component of unproven performance.

What operating system is this under ? Windows 10/11 really dont perform well with HDD's anymore. What are you copying (1 large file vs 1 million small files)  ? Many small files cause alot of overhead. Is it a PMR/CMR or SMR HDD ? If its an SMR HDD (shingled magnetic recording) you might be hitting the circumstances under which it performs poorly. There's a myriad of circumstances under which poor write performance for a HDD can be completely normal.

Can you clarify if you mean that during a copy, the speed will drop (and a later copy will start at the higher speed), or from a give point, all copies become slow and there's no way to get back to the original speed? Also how full is the disk? Do you have more details about what SMART said was going wrong?

If you regularly find yourself making use of self-copying, you may wish to move any relevant work onto a Dev Drive.  Intended for software development, a major motivator for using Dev Drives is self-copy performance within the drive.  Self-copy performance is faster for two reasons: Firstly, self-copying is done via a meta-data change, not a true copy (this doesn't have the weird consequences of symlinks, since the de-duplication is at the block level, not the file level).  Secondly, Microsoft anti-malware scans are done lazily, preventing the AV from disrupting the copy process.

What sort of HDD? A "shingled drive" can be VERY slow on self copying. || Head stealing can be a thing too.


access is sometimes inexplicably slow

Most likely, that is entirely normal. In a multitasking system, any application or background services may access the disk at any point in time. When there's already 100% disk load due to heavy reading, writing or copying, those additional accesses cause head movement and significantly slow down throughput.
You can try to keep an eye on system-wide I/O activity (e.g. in Sysinternals Process Explorer) to diagnose. Generally, if you need to handle large files on a regular basis and have significant background activity, or if you want to speed up disk access altogether you should consider upgrading to an SSD.

it could be the power supply, the motherboard, or the cable

The cable might be true - just check the system log or try another cable - but PSU or mainboard wouldn't slow down access/throughput but would crash/reboot the system altogether. The cable is somewhat unlikely though if the slowdown only happens sometimes and is not increasing in frequency.
